# OpenJPA build failure

Tags: java, maven, build, openjpa

I'm currently working on a fork of openJPA and I have to configure a CI tool (e.g. github actions) and sonar cloud for remote analysis but first of all I'm trying the build in the local system. The problem is that i cannot have the build succeeds in the original code, for example for the release 3.2.2. I downloaded the source code from [here](https://github.com/apache/openjpa/releases/tag/3.2.2) and I run the command `mvn -B install -DskipTest=true` but also `mvn clean install -DskipTest=true` but both fail with the following error:

```
openjpa/openjpa-lib/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/lib/conf/ConfigurationImpl.java:
[522,18] cannot access com.sun.beans.introspect.PropertyInfo
class file for com.sun.beans.introspect.PropertyInfo not found
```

I remark that the source code has not been changed yet. 
What should I try to solve? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is described in [java.beans.PropertyDescriptor "cannot access PropertyInfo" compilation error](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8212636) and the suggestion is:

> The correct fix for the user is to replace "-source 8 -target 8" with "-release 8", which will cause javac to compile against the right set of class signatures, and will successfully compile the example program.

That in turn means one of following:

- either use old version of java to build project
- specify `release` in [`maven-compiler-plugin` configuration](https://github.com/apache/openjpa/blob/master/pom.xml#L1944), i.e.:

```xml
<configuration>
  <source>${compile.class.source}</source>
  <target>${compile.class.target}</target>
  <release>8</release>
  <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added the `<release>8</release>` and it worked. Thanks.